# Android: Handle PHP response from HTTP post

Tags: php, android, http, authentication

I am trying to understand how to deal with the response I'm getting from a `PHP` login page from a `HTTP` post. Rather than make this question 3 pages long I posted links to both files you will need to see. They are both each about 100 lines of code.

--->[java](http://pastebin.com/9rG5fJe8)<--- code that handles the `HTTP` post and response

--->[php](http://pastebin.com/t1xpD18p)<--- code that validates a username/password

Now the problem. When I enter an invalid username/password I get this response

```
05-21 17:59:38.012: V/RESPONSE(24420):
        <script>window.location.href="index.php?err_msg=1";</script>
        <!--<script>window.location.href="index.php?err_msg=1";</script>-->
        <!-- <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=index.php?err_msg=1">-->
```

When the values are valid I get this response

```
05-21 17:56:54.892: V/RESPONSE(24420):              
    <script>window.location.href="welcome.php";</script>          
    <!--  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=welcome.php">   -->
    !--<script>window.location.href="index.php?err_msg=1";</script>-->  
    <!-- <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=index.php?err_msg=1">-->
```

If you look at the `PHP` file it's easy enough to see where this is coming from. I just don't know how to deal with it. Most sites I've done this with respond with "True", "1", "Success" or something else very generic for a successful or unsuccessful login. How do I handle this response? I could obviously copy paste the entire response in an `if else` statement but that seems like the wrong thing to do.

So, question: **Has anyone seen this before and what do I do with this type of response?**
Alternatively, **should I just create a web service to handle this login rather than use the default `PHP` the website developer created?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the PHP code is not intended to be used by mobile clients and its expecting its "clients" to be web browsers. Hence the use of cookies & sessions. If it were written with the perspective of providing an API then it would use authentication via HTTP headers and probably some kind of token exchange.

I think this PHP will be complicated to work with. Any way you can get the PHP to be adjusted with a more API workflow?

Comment: The short answer is no. That's basically the conclusion I've come to as well. This code just wasn't made for mobile. I didn't design the site, I was just working with what I was given. Well from what you've said it looks like I'm going to need to just design a web service to handle the mobile posts. I was going to have to anyways to deal with the SQL queries so it was inevitable I was just hoping to be able to use this login.php to handle the login part

Comment: So do you agree @Cody Caughlan? Since adjusting that code probably isn't possible

Comment: Yep, better to develop a new web service with mobile clients in mind.